# Displaying JSON data with ng-bind shows [object object]

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I'm new to angular js,I have 2 goals:

1. OnClick, display a single person's name from a JSON array,
2. Randomize name on every click

I'm stuck at the part where i need to pass the json data to the view: when i click the button i get [object object], [object object], [object object] 
Could someone please assist?

```
[
    {"name": "John"},
    {"name": "Sue"},
    {"name": "Sally"},
    {"name": "Jim"},
    {"name": "Bev"},
    {"name": "Joe"},
    {"name": "Jess"}
]
```

script

```
  var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []);
    idApp.controller('peopleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
      $scope.randomPerson = function(){
      $http.get('js/people.json').
       success(function(data) {
       $scope.person = data;
       console.log(data);
  });
 }
}]);
```

view

```
<div class="content">
 <div ng-controller="peopleCtrl">
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
   <button ng-click="randomPerson()">
    Show random person's name
   </button>
   <p ng-bind="person"></p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you are sending an array of objects from the controller to your view.

And then you directly bind the array to a `<p>` tag. So the entire array is getting displayed with object as it is unparsed on your view..

try changing

```
<p ng-bind="person"></p>
```

To :

```
<p ng-bind="person[randomIndex].name"></p>
 // here random index is a random number 
 // where range of random number generator is from 0 to length of person array
```

you can generate a random number on click of function like this. If you wanted to get between 0 and length of array, you would put:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * person.length) + 0
```

---

OR More specifically something like this ....

```
    $scope.randomPerson = function(){

      $http.get('js/people.json')
           .success(function(data) {
              $scope.person = data;
              var randomPersonIndex =Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.person.length) + 0 ;
              $scope.myRandomPerson = $scope.person[randomPersonIndex];
              console.log(data);
  });
```

And then on HTML you do ....

```
<p ng-bind="myRandomPerson.name"></p>
     // here random index is a random number
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to show a simple value after to get a random object of your array.

Something like this:

```js
var peopleApp = angular.module('peopleApp', []);
peopleApp.controller('peopleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [{
      "name": "John"
    }, {
      "name": "Sue"
    }, {
      "name": "Sally"
    }, {
      "name": "Jim"
    }, {
      "name": "Bev"
    }, {
      "name": "Joe"
    }, {
      "name": "Jess"
    }];
    $scope.person = "";
    $scope.randomize = function(count) { // This function returns a random number, between 0 to the $scope.data.length.
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * count) + 0);
    };
    $scope.randomPerson = function() { // By using array.filter you can get a specific object.
      $scope.person = $scope.data.filter(function(x) {
        return x.name;
      })[$scope.randomize($scope.data.length)]; // Getting the random object.
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="peopleApp" class="content">
  <div ng-controller="peopleCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
    <button ng-click="randomPerson()">
      Show random person's name
    </button>
    <p data-ng-bind="person.name"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

More simpler and better: Without using array.filter.

```js
var peopleApp = angular.module("peopleApp", []);
peopleApp.controller("peopleCtrl", ["$scope", "$http",
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = [{
      "name": "John"
    }, {
      "name": "Sue"
    }, {
      "name": "Sally"
    }, {
      "name": "Jim"
    }, {
      "name": "Bev"
    }, {
      "name": "Joe"
    }, {
      "name": "Jess"
    }];
    $scope.person = "";
    $scope.randomize = function(count) { // This function returns a random number, between 0 to the $scope.data.length (count).
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * count) + 0);
    };
    $scope.randomPerson = function() {
      $scope.person = $scope.data[$scope.randomize($scope.data.length)]; // Getting the random object.
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="peopleApp" class="content">
  <div ng-controller="peopleCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="name"></p>
    <button ng-click="randomPerson()">
      Show random person's name
    </button>
    <p data-ng-bind="person.name"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy just need to add "**| json**" with your function name.
for example

```
<p ng-bind="person | json"></p>
```